# IIS Certificates VS Windows Certificate

Tags: iis, certificate

I'd like to understand the link, if any, between certificates installed throug IIS and those installed through windows.

By IIS Certificates I mean the list shown when we open the "Server Certificates" on feature view on the home page of IIS Manager.

By windows I mean the default installation when we double clic a certificate and are prompted to install it. After installation we can find installed certificate via certmgr.msc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificates you see from IIS Manager Server Certificates page are a subset of certificates that IIS uses.

Certificate adding in MMC of course gives you control on all certificates of that machine.

That's the relationship between the two.